# US Green Card Holder but Indian Passport, Studying in Spain with Multi-entry Schengen Visa - UK/Ireland Visit?

Tags: schengen, uk, indian-citizens, ireland

I will be leaving for my study abroad in Spain next week and was wondering if I will need a UK/Ireland visa for a possible weekend trip up there? I know that they are not part of the Schengen visa agreement but will they require a visa for a trip that might be under 48 hours?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Indian citizens need visa for entering either the UK or Ireland, and a Schengen visa doesn't change that; neither does the length of your planned stay.

The UK does issue a category of *Visitor in Transit* visas which are valid for up to 48 hours (and are presumably easier to get than a general visitor visa for their intended users). However, that is not applicable for you -- it's only for when you're *passing through* the UK on your way to *somewhere else*, and you'd have to provide an itinerary showing that with the application. And it would still count as "needing a visa"; it must be applied for in advance, and so forth.

Comment: (+1) I am not sure if the visitor in transit visa is much easier to get, but it's cheaper.